# ASP.Net runs when published but not in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2019

I have a strange problem with a Solution that will run if I publish the files and run it in IIS, but when I try debug in Visual studio (IIS or IIS Express) and start the project it tries to loads an old version of my assembly and fails because they don't match up.

VS 2019. .Net 4.7 with .Net 2.0 Standard class lib. IIS Express 10

- I've removed the obj / bin folders.
- Deleted temp .Net files
- Deleted temp iisExpress files.
- Cleaned and rebuilt it.
- unloaded and reloaded.
- Changed settings to force rebuild.
- Checked the GAC
- Searched the file system for old DLLs etc.

When I look at the files in the bin folder they appear to be the correct ones with the correct versions. Everything builds and compiles correctly.

It is as if Visual Studio is finding an old DLL somewhere but in a location I cannot see/find.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: Goto the Debug Menu > Module window and check where they're loading, or use ProcessMonitor to see where VS is loading the DLLs. Perhaps first try to delete the Bin, Obj folders and the .suo file then build and see if that cleans it up.

Comment: IIS Express is not equivalent to IIS, can you show me the detailed error message you got?